How to solve disagrees about version of symbols?
I am working on a kernel module, after insmod I got such errors in dmesg:
[ 5839.116224] mcswap: disagrees about version of symbol rdma_leave_multicast
[ 5839.116234] mcswap: Unknown symbol rdma_leave_multicast (err -22)
[ 5839.116293] mcswap: disagrees about version of symbol __ib_alloc_pd
[ 5839.116296] mcswap: Unknown symbol __ib_alloc_pd (err -22)
[ 5839.116314] mcswap: disagrees about version of symbol rdma_resolve_addr
[ 5839.116317] mcswap: Unknown symbol rdma_resolve_addr (err -22)                                                   [ 5839.116360] mcswap: disagrees about version of symbol ib_process_cq_direct
[ 5839.116364] mcswap: Unknown symbol ib_process_cq_direct (err -22)
[ 5839.116383] mcswap: disagrees about version of symbol ib_event_msg
[ 5839.116386] mcswap: Unknown symbol ib_event_msg (err -22)
[ 5839.116423] mcswap: disagrees about version of symbol rdma_create_ah
[ 5839.116426] mcswap: Unknown symbol rdma_create_ah (err -22)
[ 5839.116459] mcswap: disagrees about version of symbol __rdma_create_kernel_id
[ 5839.116462] mcswap: Unknown symbol __rdma_create_kernel_id (err -22)
[ 5839.116477] mcswap: disagrees about version of symbol rdma_resolve_route
[ 5839.116479] mcswap: Unknown symbol rdma_resolve_route (err -22)                                                  [ 5839.116488] mcswap: disagrees about version of symbol rdma_bind_addr
[ 5839.116490] mcswap: Unknown symbol rdma_bind_addr (err -22)
[ 5839.116504] mcswap: disagrees about version of symbol rdma_create_qp
[ 5839.116507] mcswap: Unknown symbol rdma_create_qp (err -22)
[ 5839.116529] mcswap: disagrees about version of symbol ib_query_port
[ 5839.116532] mcswap: Unknown symbol ib_query_port (err -22)
[ 5839.116548] mcswap: disagrees about version of symbol __ib_alloc_cq
[ 5839.116551] mcswap: Unknown symbol __ib_alloc_cq (err -22)
[ 5839.116571] mcswap: disagrees about version of symbol rdma_destroy_qp
[ 5839.116573] mcswap: Unknown symbol rdma_destroy_qp (err -22)                                                     [ 5839.116596] mcswap: disagrees about version of symbol rdma_destroy_ah_user
[ 5839.116598] mcswap: Unknown symbol rdma_destroy_ah_user (err -22)
[ 5839.116614] mcswap: disagrees about version of symbol ib_destroy_cq_user
[ 5839.116616] mcswap: Unknown symbol ib_destroy_cq_user (err -22)                                                  [ 5839.116624] mcswap: disagrees about version of symbol rdma_connect                                               [ 5839.116626] mcswap: Unknown symbol rdma_connect (err -22)                                                        [ 5839.116641] mcswap: disagrees about version of symbol ib_wc_status_msg                                           [ 5839.116643] mcswap: Unknown symbol ib_wc_status_msg (err -22)                                                    [ 5839.116659] mcswap: disagrees about version of symbol ib_free_cq                                                 [ 5839.116662] mcswap: Unknown symbol ib_free_cq (err -22)                                                          [ 5839.116668] mcswap: disagrees about version of symbol rdma_destroy_id                                            [ 5839.116671] mcswap: Unknown symbol rdma_destroy_id (err -22)                                                     [ 5839.116684] mcswap: disagrees about version of symbol rdma_join_multicast                                        [ 5839.116686] mcswap: Unknown symbol rdma_join_multicast (err -22)
[ 5839.116704] mcswap: disagrees about version of symbol ib_dealloc_pd_user
[ 5839.116707] mcswap: Unknown symbol ib_dealloc_pd_user (err -22)

I compile the module by:
EXTRA_CFLAGS += -D_GNU_SOURCE
KDIR ?= /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build
obj-m := mcswap.o

all:
        $(info EXTRA_CFLAGS = $(EXTRA_CFLAGS))
        make -C $(KDIR) M=$(shell pwd) modules

clean:
        make -C $(KDIR) M=$(shell pwd) clean

The modinfo of the module mcswap.ko is:
filename:       /home/shufan/swapmon_fs/mcswap.ko
license:        GPL v2
version:        1.1.0
description:    Low latency and memory efficient paging over RDMA
srcversion:     6298CBD0C14DEC4EE9BC7AF
depends:        rdma_cm,ib_core
retpoline:      Y
name:           mcswap
vermagic:       5.15.0-127-generic SMP mod_unload modversions
parm:           endpoint:IP address and port number of memoryservers in n.n.n.n:n form (array of charp)
parm:           sport:int
parm:           server_port:Port number that memory servers are listening on
parm:           cip:string
parm:           client_ip:IP address in n.n.n.n form of the interface usedfor communicating with the memory servers
parm:           enable_async_mode:Enable asynchronous stores/loads but requires appropriate kernel patch (default=0) (int)
parm:           enable_poll_mode:int

The uname -r returns 5.15.0-127-generic, and the vermagic seems to obey the uname -r.
I guess it is related to vermagic of mcswap.ko and modules it depends on. So I checked rdma_cm and ib_core.
modinfo of rdma_cm
filename:       /lib/modules/5.15.0-127-generic/updates/dkms/rdma_cm.ko
license:        Dual BSD/GPL
description:    Generic RDMA CM Agent
author:         Sean Hefty
srcversion:     E96BA00E51632F4FDED1980
depends:        ib_core,ib_cm,iw_cm,mlx_compat
retpoline:      Y
name:           rdma_cm
vermagic:       5.15.0-127-generic SMP mod_unload modversions
sig_id:         PKCS#7
signer:         oem Secure Boot Module Signature key
sig_key:        62:A8:41:71:C1:0E:23:88:D2:17:B3:9C:FD:B8:CE:F8:49:6D:6F:58
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
signature:      6F:0A:E5:98:79:70:DC:A5:F2:1F:89:97:A6:ED:4E:33:2C:4D:BB:37:
                95:57:F5:B7:2D:51:26:C2:FB:4E:39:94:92:AA:14:3B:25:99:13:36:
                78:10:B4:A0:E4:E8:00:D5:BD:B4:1F:D8:15:DA:3F:8C:EF:5A:7A:E5:
                E2:2A:0C:99:A0:9F:EB:B5:21:4E:58:8B:8D:3A:B7:CB:9B:8B:B9:04:
                BC:3A:0F:8C:D8:9C:55:CF:1E:4D:1C:69:A7:34:85:05:16:3E:3D:AB:
                4E:1B:8D:C3:B9:3A:B7:CD:98:A3:01:FB:37:AB:49:11:A8:37:18:7A:
                AF:34:D9:D7:20:D2:AE:7C:8D:41:CF:A5:9F:CB:E4:93:53:A6:7A:97:
                FB:E0:BC:E2:9B:CF:77:2A:22:B5:18:CB:8C:30:88:E0:71:DA:51:21:
                F4:7F:51:D6:AD:E7:D1:16:46:45:04:A8:E5:84:2E:90:F4:D1:FE:1C:
                04:AD:F8:76:9A:4F:B2:5A:1D:C3:B6:BD:96:34:A3:B8:6F:ED:B4:75:
                1B:B4:FE:58:1E:F0:47:F4:32:84:DD:51:D1:6F:AA:65:DE:B8:8E:FB:
                BF:B4:70:22:65:E3:5C:A4:F0:AD:46:98:CF:F8:A1:74:46:90:E5:EF:
                CE:64:E6:86:8B:F0:FE:29:7F:E2:C1:2E:B5:1E:76:34

modinfo of ib_core
filename:       /lib/modules/5.15.0-127-generic/updates/dkms/ib_core.ko
alias:          rdma-netlink-subsys-4
license:        Dual BSD/GPL
description:    core kernel InfiniBand API
author:         Roland Dreier
alias:          net-pf-16-proto-20
alias:          rdma-netlink-subsys-5
import_ns:      DMA_BUF
srcversion:     FEC99D33844FCB00B111381
depends:        mlx_compat
retpoline:      Y
name:           ib_core
vermagic:       5.15.0-127-generic SMP mod_unload modversions
sig_id:         PKCS#7
signer:         oem Secure Boot Module Signature key
sig_key:        62:A8:41:71:C1:0E:23:88:D2:17:B3:9C:FD:B8:CE:F8:49:6D:6F:58
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
signature:      B2:18:9E:D0:D5:F9:ED:2F:A9:85:38:CF:C2:45:1D:E3:9C:71:D1:A8:
                72:73:B5:40:C5:53:C5:5D:B3:9C:A9:8B:56:50:D3:64:14:C9:27:0D:
                64:6C:45:4A:5A:5E:6D:BC:28:82:F1:A5:02:BC:61:44:8E:0C:6D:46:
                B0:A4:3E:84:1B:EC:78:0F:FB:2A:B2:8A:CC:4D:CC:48:C7:CC:87:77:
                74:39:FC:3A:BC:F9:D6:81:D1:81:A7:3D:0F:C0:7F:07:6C:4C:35:82:
                2B:45:7D:05:41:EF:85:2F:11:E6:40:91:9E:DE:D4:6D:A0:D2:8B:CF:
                71:27:7F:A7:D4:BD:65:3F:DB:05:6F:97:28:C3:3C:8E:16:CC:5F:00:
                FB:0D:33:8B:11:BF:70:07:8B:42:DE:EC:49:14:E3:C8:B9:95:79:60:
                F2:6F:35:89:4B:5D:61:AF:20:CA:B0:80:26:71:E0:DF:1A:10:CC:BB:
                57:41:2D:F2:6A:59:8F:AD:01:26:13:E6:AD:59:EA:52:82:7E:05:B9:
                12:8C:37:C4:AD:03:73:97:DE:BA:E8:38:5B:83:A8:38:36:AD:D6:07:
                D8:96:7B:55:92:ED:4A:00:BB:09:C9:D6:62:24:A6:6A:D1:08:29:1E:
                AB:A3:55:E5:76:4D:74:00:7B:88:AF:65:E3:4A:2B:B8
parm:           send_queue_size:Size of send queue in number of work requests (int)
parm:           recv_queue_size:Size of receive queue in number of work requests (int)
parm:           mad_smp_window:Maximun number of outgoing SMP requests (int)
parm:           netns_mode:Share device among net namespaces; default=1 (shared) (bool)
parm:           force_mr:Force usage of MRs for RDMA READ/WRITE operations (bool)

The vermagics of these three modules are consistent, so I don't know if it cause the problem.
I checked Disagrees about version of symbol symbol_name after insmod for answers, but I did not solve the problem. This do show me a way to check the Module.symvers. However, /home/shufan/swapmon_fs/Module.symvers is empty. So I checked /usr/src.
# inside /usr/src/linux-headers-5.15.0-127-generic/Module.symvers
0xbb93cce9  ib_free_cq  drivers/infiniband/core/ib_core EXPORT_SYMBOL   

# inside /usr/src/ofa_kernel/x86_64/5.15.0-127-generic/Module.symvers
0x4d53afee  ib_free_cq  /var/lib/dkms/mlnx-ofed-kernel/23.10.OFED.23.10.1.1.9.1/build/drivers/infiniband/core/ib_core   EXPORT_SYMBOL

I do not know if it is the reason why there's disagrees about version of symbol. Why modinfo ib_core shows the filename is filename:       /lib/modules/5.15.0-127-generic/updates/dkms/ib_core.ko, and two Module.symvers have another two file paths? Is this the root cause of my problem?

Did you install the mellanox OFED driver package? There's at least one other package with a similar complaint - https://doc.beegfs.io/latest/release_notes.html under known limitations and tracking back from an ubuntu bug with a very similar symbol error stack. If you don't actually need the mellanox ofed driver package, I would stick with the OS supplied infiniband stack

Thank you for the information. I found there is /usr/src/mlnx-ofed-kernel-23.10.OFED.23.10.1.1.9.1, I will try to remove it.
